# ¿Cómo colocar el icono al titulo en la pestaña?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

Ya probe con todos los que encontre en esta pagina y no pude con archivos icon png y gifs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>titulo</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          
      </head>
      <body>
```

---

ya intente así, de las dos formas y mezcladas y sigo sin poder mira[image: es mi codigo ayuda]

Comment: Busca por "favicon"

Comment: En alguna ocasión me ha pasado que el favicon se queda en caché por días. Presiona CTRL+F5 en el browser para obligar a actualizarlo.

Comment: y tu icono se llama favicon.ico? o tiene otro nombre?

Comment: Sí se llama favicon.ico y no funciona

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
```

Este es el código que debes poner dentro del meta y tu imagen debe ser formato .ico, puedes [convertirla aquí](https://imagen.online-convert.com/es/convertir-a-ico)

Answer (score 1):

Ampliando la respuesta de Harrison Olivera:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

El icono debe llamarse favicon.ico y estar en formato .ico. También puedes usar el sitio https://www.favicon-generator.org/